# Optimizing a function containing a complex exponential

Tags: performance-tuning, complex

I've noticed the following significant different in performance for different formulations of the same function:

```
Exp[-t - 256 I Pi t] == Exp[-t] Exp[-256 I Pi t]
Table[Exp[-t - 256 I Pi t], {t, 0, 1, 1/30000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Table[Exp[-t] Exp[-256 I Pi t], {t, 0, 1, 1/30000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* True, 0.765, 0.496 *)
```

I've got a function with the form below, which oddly splits the difference

```
func[a_, b_] := Exp[-a t] Exp[-b I Pi t]
func[1, 256] == Exp[-t - 256 I Pi t]
Table[func[1, 256], {t, 0, 1, 1/30000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* True, 0.614 *)
```

The way *Mathematica* is storing the complex exponential seems to be the slower one:

```
Exp[-t - 256 I Pi t]
Table[%, {t, 0, 1, 1/30000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Exp[-t] Exp[-256 I Pi t]
Table[%, {t, 0, 1, 1/30000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

The issue does appear to be caused by the presence of complex values

```
Exp[-t - 256  Pi t] == Exp[-t] Exp[-256  Pi t]
Table[Exp[-t - 256  Pi t], {t, 0, 1, 1/30000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Table[Exp[-t] Exp[-256  Pi t], {t, 0, 1, 1/30000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* True, 0.37, 0.37 *)
```

I can reproduce this behavior in v9 and v10 on Win 7/64-bit.  I am looking for insight into how one might achieve the speeds observed when the exponential terms are not combined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Sorry, this is too long for a comment, but I thought it might help!*

---

### Update

I also tried, interestingly,

```
c = Table[Exp[-t (1 + 256 I Pi )], {t, 0, 1, 1/30000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* 0.109373 seconds *)

d = Table[Exp[t (-1 - 256 I Pi )], {t, 0, 1, 1/30000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* 0.140624 seconds *)
```

Though this method in fact produces a slightly different list than the options below. For example,

```
a - c
(* {0, E^(-(1/30000) - (16 I \[Pi])/1875) - E^((-1 - 256 I \[Pi])/30000), ..., 0} *)

N[a] - N[c]
(* {0., 0. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I, ... , 0.} *)

Chop[N[a] - N[c]]
(* {0, 0, 0, 0, ..., 0} *)
```

So one has to do a bit of manipulation to get the same answer!

---

### Original comment

I tried the following.

```
a = Table[Exp[-t - 256 I Pi t], {t, 0, 1, 1/30000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
b = Table[Exp[-t] Exp[-256 I Pi t], {t, 0, 1, 1/30000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* 0.390862 seconds *)
(* 0.250003 seconds *)

a == b
(* True *)
```

I then put Mathematica in Debug mode as per [Profiling from Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7768/profiling-from-mathematica) and ran this:

```
Table[Exp[-t - 256 I Pi t], {t, 0, 1, 1/30000}]; // RuntimeTools`Profile
Table[Exp[-t] Exp[-256 I Pi t], {t, 0, 1, 1/30000}]; // RuntimeTools`Profile
```

The following images are the output, and might help with your question:

> I am looking for insight into how one might achieve the speeds
>   observed when the exponential terms are not combined.

[image]

Finally, if you then perform the same test on the function in my update posted above, the result is thus:

[image]