# The speed of Sum[] varies strangely

Tags: performance-tuning, summation

I was curious about the difference in speed between `Total` and `Sum`. I found out `Total` was faster. However on another occasion I used a longer list and then the result was reversed. 
Upon closer inspection, I saw that `Sum` behaved strangely, see the repetitive code below:

```
Sum[x, {x, 1, 10^4}] // AbsoluteTiming
Sum[x, {x, 1, 10^5}] // AbsoluteTiming
Sum[x, {x, 1, 10^6}] // AbsoluteTiming
Sum[x, {x, 1, 10^7}] // AbsoluteTiming
Sum[x, {x, 1, 10^8}] // AbsoluteTiming
Sum[x, {x, 1, 10^9}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.000377, 50005000}
>
> {0.002676, 5000050000}
>
> {**0.162434**, 500000500000}
>
> {0.000157, 50000005000000}
>
> {0.000112, 5000000050000000}
>
> {0.000110, 500000000500000000}

I can not make any sense of the results above.

Compare those with the more expected results from `Total`

```
Total[Range[10^4]] // AbsoluteTiming
Total[Range[10^5]] // AbsoluteTiming
Total[Range[10^6]] // AbsoluteTiming
Total[Range[10^7]] // AbsoluteTiming
Total[Range[10^8]] // AbsoluteTiming
Total[Range[10^9]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.000115, 50005000}
>
> {0.000931, 5000050000}
>
> {0.010395, 500000500000}
>
> {0.101801, 50000005000000}
>
> {1.166246, 5000000050000000}
>
> {12.470277, 500000000500000000}

Can anyone explain what causes this strange behavior ?

Comment: `Total` will most surely sum blindly, while `Sum[]` could use known properties (at least it will try when `n` is large enough)

Comment: For simple problems do the sum symbolically. `sum[n_Integer?Positive] = Sum[x, {x, 1, n}]`

Comment: @belisarius - so you mean, Sum's algorithm changes when the list reaches a certain length?

Comment: @MathLind Well, I can't be sure, but it won't surprise me if it does

Comment: "If a sum cannot be carried out explicitly by adding up a finite number of terms, Sum will attempt to find a symbolic result. In this case, f is first evaluated symbolically." Presumably, "cannot be carried out explicitly" translates approximately to more than 10^6 terms.

Comment: I did your `Sum`s on my Mathematica in a different order and got qualitatively different results. The 10^6 took a lot longer, but the 10^7 took even longer. Then, 10^8 was very quick. When using Mathematica for timing, be sure to clear caches/etc to make sure you're not getting inaccurate times. Restarting Mathematica each time might also make the timing more accurate.

Comment: Doesn't Mathematica know that this sum is n(n+1)/2?

Comment: @JohnMcGee: Yes, when it is input as an indefinite sum, or when the summation bounds are symbolic. When it is given a numeric range, it looks like it just adds up the numbers manually. See my answer for an illustration of this behavior.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`Sum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html) uses more than one [`Method`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Method.html).  By default it selects automatically.  If you specify one of them you should see more consistent behavior:

```
SetOptions[Sum, Method -> "Procedural"];

Table[
  Sum[x, {x, 1, 10^n}] // AbsoluteTiming,
  {n, 4, 9}
] // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  0.001000 & 50005000 \\
>  0.003000 & 5000050000 \\
>  0.011001 & 500000500000 \\
>  0.104006 & 50000005000000 \\
>  0.768044 & 5000000050000000 \\
>  10.313590 & 500000000500000000 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Symbolic summation:

```
SetOptions[Sum, Method -> "RationalFunction"];

Table[
  Sum[x, {x, 1, 10^n}] // AbsoluteTiming,
  {n, 4, 9}
] // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  0.002000 & 50005000 \\
>  0.002000 & 5000050000 \\
>  0.001000 & 500000500000 \\
>  0.002000 & 50000005000000 \\
>  0.002000 & 5000000050000000 \\
>  0.001000 & 500000000500000000 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: Thank you for a clear answer. I still find it peculiar that Sum is optimized in such a way as to give rise to a 1000-fold speed jump at a certain list length. What I mean by that is, what it apparently needs roughly 10^7 of list length to realize, it should have detected earlier in shorter lists.

Comment: @MathLind Thanks for the Accept.  I think it is a matter of *Mathematica* not knowing in advance which method will be fastest.  Even the "slow" attempt takes under a fifth of a second.  You can let *Mathematica* try multiple methods in parallel by using `Method -> "ParallelFirstToSucceed"` but I think you will find that the overhead of that is often slower than the default behavior.  Perhaps this could be better optimized but there are other aspects of *Mathematica* that I consider in far greater need of optimization; specifically the pattern matching.

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard For me this was an awakening in the context of optimizing code (programs) containing many built-in functions that behave in this way. Without profiling tools, this may possibly require laborious and careful parameter study of all the built-in functions within the expected ranges. A challenge but still very interesting.

Comment: @MathLind Indeed *Mathematica* can be fiddly that way.  There *is* a profiling tool built in, detailed here: [(7768)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7768/121).  It has a few quirks but it seems to work acceptably accurately.

Answer (score 8):

The pattern becomes more obvious when plotted:

```
ListLogPlot[
 Table[First@AbsoluteTiming@Sum[x, {x, 1, Round[10^k]}], {k, 1, 10, 
   0.1}], PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

This appears to be consistent with Bob Hanlon's observation that `Sum` attempts to explicitly sum when the number of terms is considered tractable (the time expense of which is linear), and then search for general solutions after that and use bound substitution (which is fast, and proceeds in constant time). Mr. Wizard's answer provides more details.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an area where Mathematica can be improved.
Mathematica knows the general sum with increment of 1.
Applying it is very fast.

```
In[1]  sn = Sum[x, {x, a, b}]
Out[1] -(1/2) (a-b-1) (a+b)
In[2 ] sn /. {a -> 1, b -> 10^35} // AbsoluteTiming
Out[2] {0.,5000000000000000000000000000000000050000000000000000000000000000000000}
```

We could define a function for this

```
FastSum[x_, {x_, a_, b_}] := 1/2 (b - a + 1) (a + b);
```

Comment: I think you ought to include the time it took to figure out the general sum (the first step).