# Timing mathematica code

Tags: timing

I have a collection of functions (Modules) and I wish to find out which sub-routines inside the code take up most time. I have done this by wrapping individual code blocks with

```
Print[Row[{"comment: ", AbsoluteTiming[ --- code --- ]}]];
```

This is tedious to do, and it is also tedious to remove these code blocks again once I am done with my optimization.

What I am looking for is a routine that can be turned on and off (e.g. by setting an Option), something like

```
timeIt[ --- code --- ,"comment"];
```

that can be left in place - it will simply execute the code when the Option is set to not report timing, and it will execute the code and return the timings when it is turned on.

So far, when I tried to put my `Print[...]` construct into an external module it worked, but it always returned a time of 0.

Here is the code that I have tried:

```
Clear[timeIt];
Options[timeIt] = {debugTiming -> True};
SetAttributes[timeIt, HoldFirst];
timeIt[f_, comment_: "", OptionsPattern[]] := 
  If[OptionValue[debugTiming] === True, 
   Print @ Row[{comment,": ",First@AbsoluteTiming[ReleaseHold@f]}], 
   ReleaseHold@f];
```

Any suggestions of how to do this properly?

Comment: Before I dig into this have you seen and understood this Q&A?: [(7768)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7768/121)

Comment: Also, are you having any problems with your implementation of `timeIt`?  Are you requesting a code review?  The first thing I note is that you do not need `ReleaseHold` as there is no actual `Hold` imposed by the use of `HoldFirst`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have seen the Q&A you linked to. However, my program is longish and I don't want the whole thing profiled, just sub-parts of the code.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I first tried without any "Hold". My impression was that the code wrapped by timeIt is executed before being passed to timeIt, and there was nothig left to be executed inside timeIt, thus a timing of 0 is returned. Then I tried all kinds of "Hold" (HoldAllComplete etc) but it did not change the outcome.

Comment: What I meant is that you can use e.g. `SetAttributes[fn, HoldFirst]` and then `fn[x_] := AbsoluteTiming[x]` as the argument of `fn` will be passed unevaluated to `AbsoluteTiming` and then evaluated normally; you do not need an *additional* release.  Again I ask: are you having any functional problems with your implementation?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, the implementation works in the sense that it Prints and reports the timing (always 0, though) when the option is set to "True", and it runs the code without printing the report with the option set to "False". Importantly, the main code itself is not disrupted by inserting the timeIt Function and it returns the same result. I just don't get the timing, which is what I want in the first place.

Comment: Other than a small syntax error which I just corrected your code appears to work correctly for me, returning non-zero timing results.  For example: `foo[] := Module[{a = 1, b = 2},
  timeIt[Pause[1.3]; a + b, "test"]
  ]` and then calling `foo[]` yields `test: 1.301074` -- what do you get?

Comment: hmmm... It works for me too. Must be something how the original code is implemented... I will check.

Comment: @Thomas I had a similar problem: I wanted to analyze the timing of various functions without putting `AbsoluteTiming` everywhere. I found that `TraceScan` did what I wanted, see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157002/timing-functions-with-sow-reap-and-absolutetiming).

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I would do:

```
ClearAll[timed];
SetAttributes[timed, HoldFirst];
timed[expr_, timeItQ_] := Module[
  {
   timing,
   time,
   result
   },
  Switch[ timeItQ,
   True, (
     timing = Timing[ expr];
    Sow[ First @ timing ]; (* maybe use tags like SymbolName @ expr *)         
    result = Last@timing;
    ),
   False, result = expr
   ];
  result
  ]

Clear[myfunction];
myfunction[x_] := Table[ "Do Something";, {x}]

ClearAll[main];
Options[main] =
  {
   "timeMyFunction" -> True
   (* options for other functions *)
   };

main[opts : OptionsPattern[{main}]] := Module[
  {},
  timed[myfunction[10000000], OptionValue["timeMyFunction"] ]
  (* rest of code *)
  ]
```

Then you can do

```
Reap [ main[] ][[2]]

(* {{2.823618}} *)
```

I thought you wanted to time different functions and wanted to have some options to declare for which at the part of the main program. That is how this example is constructed so the `Reap` will collect the timings. One can use tags for the `Sow` expressions of course if the timings are to be collected for more than one function at any run.

To make this nicer you might put a `timedMyFunction` for all the possible function candidates in the main part so when different parameters are given, so that it is nicer to read.