# Timing functions with Sow / Reap and AbsoluteTiming

Tags: timing, sow-reap

I have a main function `f[x]` that calls three sub-functions:

```
f1[x_] := x^2;
f2[x_] := x + 5;
f3[x_] := Sin[x];

f[x_] := f1[x] + f2[f3[x]]
```

(In my real application, the functions are more complicated.)

I would like to time how long `f1`, `f2`, and `f3` take to execute, *without re-defining them or `f`*.

One idea is to temporarily replace `f1` with a function that times `f1` and uses `Sow` to return the time, like this:

```
With[
 {
  f1[x_] := Block[{t, z}, {t, z} = AbsoluteTiming[f1[x]]; Sow[t]; Return[z]]
  },
 Reap[f[x]]
 ]
```

Or this:

```
Block[
 {
  f1 = Function[x, Block[{t, z}, {t, z} = AbsoluteTiming[f1[x]]; Sow[t]; Return[z]]]
  },
 Reap[f[x]]
 ]
```

(And do the same for `f2` and `f3`)

However, both these forms produce errors.

Is there a way to temporarily "inject" AbsoluteTiming into a function, and use Sow/Reap to obtain timing information?

**Update**

It seems that TraceScan was just what I needed:

```
g[x_] := (Pause[.1]; Cos[x])
h[x_] := (Pause[.2]; Tan[x])
f[x_] := h[x] + Sin[g[x]]

Block[
 {list = {}, t},
 TraceScan[
  (t = Now) &,
  f[x],
  _g | _h,
  (AppendTo[list, {#, Now - t}];) &
  ];
 Column[list]
 ]
```

returns

```
{h[x],0.201649s}
{g[x],0.100481s}
```

Thanks Carl Woll for your example use of `TracePrintEvaluate`!

Comment: i think you need to elaborate on what you are actually trying to accomplish. If you are modifying the calling code with `Reap` why not just directly use `AbsolutTiming` ?

Comment: I have a big complicated function that calls several other complicated sub-functions. The big function runs slowly, so I'd like to append a section to my notebook that performs a timing analysis. However, I would prefer to *not* re-write my functions to include `AbsoluteTiming` because I feel it would distract the reader from the main goal of my code. That is, I would like to perform a timing investigation *after* the functions have been defined and demonstrated, without modifying them with timing code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One idea is to use my [`TracePrintEvaluate`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/137615/45431) function:

```
TracePrintEvaluate[f[x], _f1|_f2|_f3, "Timing"->True]
```

> f1[x]
>
> f2[f3[x]]
>
> f3[x]
>
> f2[Sin[x]]
>
> 5 + x^2 + Sin[x]

Clicking on any of the trace outputs will show what the expression evaluated to, and then the time it took to do the evaluation. Below, I show the output after clicking on each of the trace outputs twice:

```
TracePrintEvaluate[f[x], _f1|_f2|_f3, "Timing"->True]
```

> 0.000077
>
> 0.000404
>
> 0.000038
>
> 0.000032
>
> 5 + x^2 + Sin[x]

Note that using `TracePrintEvaluate`, just like using any `Trace*` function, will instrument the evaluation process, hence the timings shown will be larger than the actual timings. However, it will give you an idea of where slow points are so that you can speed up those portions of the code.

Comment: Thanks Carl, that's a neat tool. Reading your code inspired me to explore TraceScan, and I think it will work. I've added my findings to my post.