# Fast value extraction for refreshing large data

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, parallelization, compile

I am trying to fine tune a procedure to reduce its running time. It involves two large arrays "data" and "positions":

```
size=10^6;
data=RandomReal[1,size];
positions=RandomInteger[{1,size},24*size];
```

Here, "positions" never changes. However, "data" is constantly changing along the procedure and every time this happens, I need to produce the array

```
evalData=data[[positions]];
```

My questions is, considering both the sizes and the fact that `positions` is fixed, what would be the fastest way of refreshing `evalData` every time `data` changes?

I have tried compiling `Part` but it takes about the same time as using `Part` directly. Also, `ParallelMap` and `ParallelTable` are very slow (even when I tried it on a computer with 10 cores). I also thought about compiling `Part` together with `positions` but this seems to take too much memory. Any advice?

***UPDATE 1:***
Perhaps my first question was overly simplified. This is in the context of a gradient descent algorithm, and the array `positions` actually has rank two.

```
size=10^6;
data=RandomReal[1,size];
positions=RandomInteger[{1,size},{6*size,4}];
```

I am trying to optimize the following code:

```
Do[
dataTemp = Transpose[Map[data[[#]] &, Transpose[positions]]];
dataDescent = compiledFunction[dataTemp];
data=data-0.5*dataDescent;
,1000]
```

where `compiledFunction` is listable and performs a computation on each array of size 4 stored in `dataTemp`, in parallel, and it is currently much faster than the line

```
dataTemp = Transpose[Map[data[[#]] &, Transpose[positions]]];
```

I could store `transposedPositions=Transpose[positions];` and save some time by instead calling

```
dataTemp = Transpose[Map[data[[#]] &, transposedPositions]];
```

but it is not a huge improvement.

***UPDATE 2:***

Found the following related unanswered [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133243/how-to-make-reading-from-long-lists-faster)

Comment: This is a tricky situation to optimize, since the best approach for it probably depends on what exactly you're doing with `evalData`.

Comment: The `evalData=data[[positions]]` call takes about 0.5 seconds on my machine. For comparison, pure allocation of an array of this size using `evalData=ConstantArray[0.,24*size]` takes close to 0.1 seconds, a similar order of magnitude. Btw, I do wonder how this call can be the bottleneck of any computation. Unless of course you do not actually use most of the entries in `evalData`, in which case, why construct it at all?

Comment: I have updated the question to add more context.

Comment: Have you tried `Extract`?

Comment: Here is a try with `Extract`: `data = RandomReal[1, 10^6];
positions = RandomInteger[{1, Length[data]}, 6*10^6];
AbsoluteTiming[data[[positions]];] // First
positions = positions /. i_Integer :> {i};
AbsoluteTiming[Extract[data, positions];] // First` gives `0.085491

0.554953` It is slower than `Part`.

Comment: Here is something puzzling. `In[325]:= data = RandomReal[1, 10^6];
positions = RandomInteger[{1, Length[data]}, {4, 6*10^6}];
positionsFlat = Flatten[positions];
RepeatedTiming[Map[data[[#]] &, positions];] // First
RepeatedTiming[{data[[positions[[1]]]], data[[positions[[2]]]], 
    data[[positions[[3]]]], data[[positions[[4]]]]};] // First
RepeatedTiming[data[[positionsFlat]];] // First

Out[328]= 0.436071

Out[329]= 0.45696

Out[330]= 0.554789` 3rd case  consistently gets larger times, despite performing the same evaluations with less functions being called.

Comment: Use a packed array for positions in using Extract[]. Then Extract[] is twice as fast as Part[] in Mma online. (Your data is not very big. Is that the typical size?)

Comment: Oh, didn't realize that that ReplaceAll unpacks the array. Fixed it, but it only makes `Extract` have the same time as `Part` on my machine. (Also, in my application I would have multiple `data` arrays, say 100 of them, and they would all go through the same procedure in parallel)