# Difference in performance for making diagonal checks

Tags: performance-tuning

In Leonid Shifrin's book (page 357 or http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node558.html) i am getting opposite performance speeds for two implementations that check whether a matrix is indeed a diagonal matrix

The book mentions the two constructs:

```
diagonalQ2[m_?MatrixQ]/;Equal@@Dimensions[m]:=
(Total@*Abs@*Flatten@*Rest@*Transpose)[MapIndexed[RotateLeft[#1,First[#2]-1]&,m]] === 0;
```

second construct:

```
diagonalQNew1[m_?MatrixQ] /; Equal @@ Dimensions[m] := Module[{len = Length[m]},
Flatten[MapThread[Delete, {m, Range[len]}]] === Array[0 &, {len*(len - 1)}]
];
```

the book claims that `diagonalQNew1` is faster than `diagonalQ2`.
Leonid mentions two tests:

```
testiden = IdentityMatrix[400];
testmatr = Array[Random[]&, {400,400}];
```

**his results**:

```
diagonalQ2[testiden]//Timing (* 0.07, True *)
diagonalQ2[testmatr]//Timing (* 0.261, False *)
```

compared to

```
diagonalQNew1[testiden]//Timing (* 0.02, True *)
diagonalQNew1[testmatr]//Timing (* 0.17, False *)
```

**my results (version 11.1)**

However, in my test with version 11.1 I have observed `diagonalQ2` to be approximately 4X faster.

```
diagonalQ2[testiden] // RepeatedTiming (* {0.0038, True} *)
diagonalQ2[testmatr] // RepeatedTiming (* {0.004, False} *)
```

versus

```
diagonalQNew1[testmatr] // RepeatedTiming (* {0.019, False} *)
diagonalQNew1[testiden] // RepeatedTiming (* {0.013, True} *)
```

I am confused as to what can be the cause of this significant perfomance increase?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a significant performance increase. The usage of `@*` suggests that the book was written with at least Mathematica 10.0, but I get roughly the same performance in both version 10.0 and 11.

Comment: @C.E. let me put it this way: why is `diagonalQNew1` performing faster than `diagonalQ2`

Comment: @C.E. sorry but I have used `@*` in the code. The code in the book goes without it.

Comment: ok, then maybe the tests are accurate for an even older version, like 9. What I'd do to figure out why one is faster than the other is to use ``Runtime`Profile`` as in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7769/731). If I had access to Mathematica 9.0, then I could also have figured out what the reason for the performance increase is by profiling the code in that version as well.