# Question about how to speed up Mathematica code

Tags: performance-tuning, number-theory, prime-numbers

When looking at the Minimal Goldbach prime partition point {p,q} for each n; where n=10^i and i = 2,3,4,...,10; I notice that these points reside in an interval with center n/2 and radius 250:

```
Clear[mgppp, lowerbound, upperbound]

mgppp[n_?EvenQ] := 
Last[ Transpose@{n - #, #} &@ 
Select[n - Prime@Range@PrimePi[n/2], PrimeQ]]

lowerbound[n_?EvenQ] := Module[{d}, {m = n/2, d = (m - 250)}; d]

upperbound[n_?EvenQ] := Module[{d}, {m = n/2, d = (m + 250)}; d]

hello = Table[{n, lowerbound[n], mgppp[n][[1]], n/2, mgppp[n][[2]], 
upperbound[n]}, {n, {10^2, 10^3, 10^4, 10^5, 10^6, 10^7, 10^8, 
 10^9, 10^10}}];TableForm[hello, 
TableHeadings -> {None, {"n", "(n/2)-250", "MGPPPp", "n/2", "MGPPPq",
 "(n/2)+250"}}, TableAlignments -> Center]
```

Mathematica takes about 45 minutes to build the above table. Notice that each lower bound value (n/2)-250 is less than p and each upper bound value (n/2)+250 is greater than q.

Now I want to verify (or not) that the same happens for ALL even n's between
10^2 and 10^10.  To simplify the number of evaluations; I compare only
the lowerbound values with the p values as follows:

```
Clear[mgppp, lowerbound]

mgppp[n_?EvenQ] := 
Last[ Transpose@{n - #, #} &@ 
Select[n - Prime@Range@PrimePi[n/2], PrimeQ]]

lowerbound[n_?EvenQ] := Module[{d}, {m = n/2, d = (m - 250)}; d]

bag = {}; For[n = 10^2, n <= 10^10, n += 2, 
If[lowerbound[n] < mgppp[n][[1]], Nothing, 
AppendTo[bag, {n, lowerbound[n], mgppp[n][[1]]}]]]; TableForm[bag, 
TableHeadings -> {None, {"n", "(n/2)-250", "MGPPPp"}}, 
TableAlignments -> Center]
```

The above evaluation is very slow and it takes days to be evaluated using my
personal computer.  I would appreciate any suggestions about how to speed up
the calculations; perhaps using "Compile" or any other method to do this.
Thank you.

Comment: One of the problems, perhaps the problem, is `PrimePi`. Your algorithm as it is written will never be faster than `PrimePi[Range[1, 10^10/2, 2]]; // AbsoluteTiming`.

Comment: You are right C.E.; thank you; that version of mpppp is slow.

The following version is much faster:

     mgppp2[n_?EvenQ] /; n > 3 := 
     Block[{m = PrimePi[n/2], p}, 
     While[! PrimeQ[q = n - (p = Prime[m])], m--]; {p, q}]

But, I still have the same evaluation issues after using this second version.

Comment: What I am concerned about is actually the `For` loop. It will call `mgpppp` or `mgppp2` once for every `n` between `10^2` and `10^8`, so it will not be faster than `PrimePi[Range[10^2, 10^10, 2]/2];` because those functions evaluate `PrimePi` for `n` divided by two. `PrimePi` appears to be slow for large `n` and that is a problem.

Comment: n is even.  m=n/2 is an integer and PrimePi[m] is then calculated.  These PrimePi[m] values fall in an interval with center n/2 and radius 250; so, computationally this shouldn’t be time exhausting.  The problem lies someplace else C.E.

Comment: You're right, I made a mistake. I posted a more careful analysis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The combination of `For` and `AppendTo` in your code is an inefficient way of substituting `Table`, and although it is not a major culprit we might as well change that. What's more serious is that if `mgppp[n][[1]]` is larger than the lower bound then you evaluate it a second time. This is an expensive function, so it shouldn't be evaluated unless it has to be evaluated, so that should also be fixed. We end up with this code:

```
Clear[mgppp, lowerbound]

mgppp[n_?EvenQ] := Last[Transpose@{n - #, #} &@Select[n - Prime@Range@PrimePi[n/2], PrimeQ]]
lowerbound[n_?EvenQ] := Module[{d}, {m = n/2, d = (m - 250)}; d]

RuntimeTools`Profile[
  res = Table[With[{y = First@mgppp[n]},
      If[lowerbound[n] < y, Nothing, {n, lowerbound[n], y}]
      ], {n, 10^2, 10^5, 2}];
  ];
```

Where I have changed the upper limit from `10^10` to `10^5` and have wrapped the whole thing with a function that does profiling. You can read about profiling Mathematica code in the Q&A [Profiling from Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7768/profiling-from-mathematica).

This code will not only run the computation but will also report (in debug mode – this is explained in the other question) on how much time each part of the code took. I changed the upper limit so that it would finish in a reasonable time. It outputs a report like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

These reports are usually straightforward to interpret, in this case, however, I'm not sure. It says that `Prime@Range@PrimePi[n/2]` took 254.6 seconds, whereas `Prime` took 88 seconds. The difference should be in the time it took to evaluate `PrimePi`, but it says that `PrimePi` only took 0.46 seconds to evaluate. I'll ask about this in the chat room to see if anyone understands this.

In either case, I believe that the time is spent evaluating built-in functions. There isn't much overhead that can be optimized. [Memoization](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/memoization-in-mathematica.html) can be used if we suspect that the code is doing the same work several times over, so I tried doing this:

```
Clear[prime, primeQ]

prime[x_] := prime[x] = Prime[x]
primeQ[x_] := primeQ[x] = PrimeQ[x]

RuntimeTools`Profile[
  res = Table[With[{y = First@mgppp[n]},
      If[lowerbound[n] < y, Nothing, {n, lowerbound[n], y}]
      ], {n, 10^2, 10^5, 2}];
  ];
```

But it didn't make it faster. So at this point, I'm wondering if this can really be optimized at the code level.

Comment: I think `Prime` and `PrimeQ` cache results.  My guess is that the 135,000,000 calls to `Prime` didn't add to the "time" of `Prime` when retrieving a cached result, but they still took around `135000000 * 10^-6` sec. to execute the function calls.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That makes sense, thank you.

Comment: I apologize for not not returning fast and proper feedback to all of your suggestions above
but, my personal computer was attacked by a virus today at work and our IT technicians had to clean my PC and I had
to re-install Mathematica and get use to a new Windows 10 Operations System.

Comment: Clear[mgppp, lowerbound, upperbound] 
mgppp[n_?EvenQ] /; n > 3 := 
 Block[{m = PrimePi[n/2], p}, 
  While[! PrimeQ[q = n - (p = Prime[m])], m--]; {p, q}]
lowerbound[n_?EvenQ] := Module[{d}, {m = n/2, d = (m - 250)}; d]
(** 10^2 to 10^3 range:  **)
hello = Table[{n, lowerbound[n], mgppp[n][[1]], n/2, mgppp[n][[2]], 
    upperbound[n], 
    If[lowerbound[n] < mgppp[n][[1]], "ok", "Not bounded"]}, {n, 10^2,
     10^3, 2}];
TableForm[hello, 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"n", "(n/2)-250", "MGPPPp", "n/2", "MGPPPq",
     "(n/2)+250", "Bounding Status"}}, TableAlignments -> Center]

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is you are generating a large number of prime pairs then using `Last` to throw most of them away. This starts in the middle and stops as soon as we find a pair:
This runs in a fraction of a second..

```
myp[n_ /; PrimeQ[n/2]] := {n/2, n/2}  (* special case if n/2 is prime *)
myp[n_?EvenQ] := Module[{y = Prime@(PrimePi[n/2]+1)},
  While[! AllTrue[{y, n - y}, PrimeQ], y = NextPrime[y]];
  {y,n-y}]
hello = Table[{n, lowerbound[n], (mm = myp[n])[[1]], n/2, mm[[2]], 
     upperbound[n]}, {n, {10^2, 10^3, 10^4, 10^5, 10^6, 10^7, 10^8, 
      10^9, 10^10}}]; // AbsoluteTiming
TableForm[hello, 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"n", "(n/2)-250", "MGPPPp", "n/2", "MGPPPq",
     "(n/2)+250"}}, TableAlignments -> Center]
```

[image]

also in your table you were calling `mgppp[n]` twice for every n. Take note how I fixed that.. (factor of two timing savings right there )

aside, we can easily find numbers that break your bounds..

```
myp[#] - #/2 &@ 12573226
mgppp[#] - #/2 &@ 12573226
```

> {-1140, 1140}
>
> {-1140, 1140}

Answer (score 0):

If we evaluate:

```
Clear[mgppp, lowerbound, upperbound] 

mgppp[n_?EvenQ] /; n > 3 := 
Block[{m = PrimePi[n/2], p}, 
While[! PrimeQ[q = n - (p = Prime[m])], m--]; {p, q}]

lowerbound[n_?EvenQ] := Module[{d}, {m = n/2, d = (m - 250)}; d]
```

(** 10^2 to 10^3 range:  **)

```
hello = Table[{n, lowerbound[n], mgppp[n][[1]], n/2, mgppp[n][[2]], 
upperbound[n], 
If[lowerbound[n] < mgppp[n][[1]], "ok", "Not bounded"]}, {n, 10^2,
 10^3, 2}];

TableForm[hello, 
TableHeadings -> {None, {"n", "(n/2)-250", "MGPPPp", "n/2", "MGPPPq",
 "(n/2)+250", "Bounding Status"}}, TableAlignments -> Center]
```

(** 10^3 to 10^4 range:  **)

```
hello2 = Table[{n, lowerbound[n], mgppp[n][[1]], n/2, mgppp[n][[2]], 
upperbound[n], 
If[lowerbound[n] < mgppp[n][[1]], "ok", "Not bounded"]}, {n, 10^3,
 10^4, 2}];

TableForm[hello2, 
TableHeadings -> {None, {"n", "(n/2)-250", "MGPPPp", "n/2", "MGPPPq",
 "(n/2)+250", "Bounding Status"}}, TableAlignments -> Center]
```

we find that the lower and upper bounds work for n in the above ranges.

If we evaluate the following:

(** 10^4 to 10^5 range:  **)

```
hello3 = Table[
If[lowerbound[n] < mgppp[n][[1]], 
Nothing, {n, lowerbound[n], mgppp[n][[1]], n/2, mgppp[n][[2]], 
 upperbound[n], "Unbounded"}], {n, 10^4, 10^5, 2}];

TableForm[hello3, 
TableHeadings -> {None, {"n", "(n/2)-250", "MGPPPp", "n/2", "MGPPPq",
 "(n/2)+250", "Bounding Status"}}, TableAlignments -> Center]
```

we find the the bounds fail for all the n values listed on the hello3 table.

The evaluations take longer when we reach the 10^5 to 10^6 range:

(** 10^5 to 10^6 range:  **)

```
hello4 = Table[
If[lowerbound[n] < mgppp[n][[1]], 
Nothing, {n, lowerbound[n], mgppp[n][[1]], n/2, mgppp[n][[2]], 
 upperbound[n], "Unbounded"}], {n, 10^5, 10^6, 2}]; 

TableForm[hello4, 
TableHeadings -> {None, {"n", "(n/2)-250", "MGPPPp", "n/2", "MGPPPq",
 "(n/2)+250", "Bounding Status"}}, TableAlignments -> Center]
```

For larger ranges the evaluations take too long.

Answer (score 0):

The n values below correspond to sequence A065978 at:
http://oeis.org/A065978

The lowerbound values below correspond to sequence A155764 at:
http://oeis.org/A155764

```
 mgppp[n_?EvenQ] /; n > 3 := 
 Block[{m = PrimePi[n/2], p}, 
 While[! PrimeQ[n - (p = Prime[m])], m--]; p]

 lowerbound[n_?EvenQ] := Module[{d}, {m = n/2, d = (m - mgppp[n])}; d]

 bag = {}; n = 4; max = -1; While[n <= 10^5, 
 If[lowerbound[n] > max, AppendTo[bag, {n, lowerbound[n]}]; 
 max = lowerbound[n]]; n++]; bag
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that I was attempting to write a program that verifies whether pre-selected lower and upper bounds for the MGPPP work for ALL even n between 10^2 and 10^10.  The purpose of the examples with tables listing the lower and upper bounds for n's that are powers of 10, was to illustrate and give a
simpler starting point to get at the ultimate task of doing this for ALL even n's in the above range. This is not the best approach to tackle this problem; a better approach is to collect the n's corresponding to the strictly-increasing distances n/2-MGPPP[n] as done in A065978 at http://oeis.org/A065978 and A155764 at http://oeis.org/A155764 where this approach is applied. Thank you all for your valuable help!