# How do I profile my own code in Mathematica?

Tags: performance-tuning, debugging

Coming from the question [Profiling from Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7768/profiling-from-mathematica) and reading [the example](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Instrumentation/tutorial/ProfileTutorial.html), I manage to reproduce it but I have no idea how to adjust it to profile my own code.

Given an example file:

```
(*example.nb*)
f[0] = 1;
g[0] = 1;
f[n_] := f[n - 1] g[n - 1]
g[n_] := (1 + g[n - 1])^2

testFunction[n_] := Table[{k, f[k], g[k]}, {k, n}]
testFunction[10] // TableForm
```

How can I profile the function `testFunction` with the tools from Mathematica to analyse it? I specifically want to use the [functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Instrumentation/tutorial/ProfileTutorial.html)

`ProfileInstrument`, `ProfileEvaluate`, `ProfileProcess[profilingData]`, and `ProfileReport`

Comment: I recommend that you use [`memoization`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/WriteAFunctionThatRemembersComputedValues.html) `f[0] = 1; g[0] = 1; f[n_Integer?Positive] := f[n] = f[n - 1] g[n - 1]; g[n_Integer?Positive] := g[n] = (1 + g[n - 1])^2;`

Comment: I don't want memorization for this contrived code, because I want to check the profiler.

Comment: ``testFunction[10] // TableForm // RuntimeTools`Profile`` works for me, ***if*** I remember to put it into debugger mode (menu Evaluation > Debugger).

Comment: @MichaelE2 this works but it's insufficient for more complicated functions. What output do you get though?

Comment: I cannot guess how. A minimal working example would help.

Comment: @MichaelE2 What do you mean you can not guess how?

Comment: The profiler works on the example you supplied. You say that `Profile[]` is "insufficient" on other examples. I don't know how it is insufficient, and I cannot guess what you mean (other than vaguely accepting that you're dissatisfied in some way). I cannot think of a solution without code to test and an understanding of the ways in which the output of `Profile[]` is unsatisfactory.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Profile does not show nested function calls. In the above dummy example, I'd like to see how often `f ` and `g` are called and how many times is spent respectively. I added the Mathematica functions I want to use to the question. I just don't understand how to use them, as the example (linked in the OP) was not very enlightening to me.

Comment: I got this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dw1lr.png following the instructions in the tutorial, which results agree with the [output of `Profile[]`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svb0d.png) in the number of function calls (timings are different, though -- not sure what they're measuring). Did following the instructions not work for you? (I followed the Collatz.m example, but put your code in the .m file.)

Comment: I followed the instrutions and replaced the collatz file with my code, but when I ran `{res, profileData} = ProfileEvaluate[Collatz[27]];` it would still show the output for Collatz. When I replaced it with my function call name, it would complain it doesn't know the name. Could you show what you did differently? [This is my](https://i.postimg.cc/XNZTZYVz/image.png) `Profile` output. I'm using Mathematica 13.2 Student edition.

Comment: I executed `ProfileEvaluate[testFunction[10]]`. If you're using the same file "Collatz.m"` and directory, then write the code file `Export[FilenameJoin[{<directory>, "Collatz.m"}], "f[0] = 1;...testFunction[n_] :=...]", "Text"]`.  It sounds like the file contains the definition of the Collatz package and the defs. of `f`, `g`, and `testFunction`.