# Precise Timing for nested functions, how to?

Tags: functions, timing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Profiling from Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7768/profiling-from-mathematica)

How can I easily get fractions of timing for each nested function?

Consider a nested call like this:

```
Total[DigitCount[Mod[(2^10000) + 1, Prime[100]]]]
```

I don't want to assign each parameter to a variable and wrap `Timing` around it, but looking for a way to wrap the hole expression with `Timing` and get fractions of total time for each function.

Comment: Related questions: [profiling-from-mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7768/profiling-from-mathematica?lq=1), and [workbench-profile-question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1786/workbench-profile-question). Not fully sure, but this one may be a dupe of one of those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Leonid Shifrin [recommendation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7768/profiling-from-mathematica?lq=1):

Put your Mathematica session in debug mode by going to `Evaluation`->`Debugger`

```
F[x_] := Total[DigitCount[Mod[(2^10000) + 1, Prime[x]]]]

Table[F[x], {100000}]; // RuntimeTools`Profile
```

[image]

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate (since it is), but you can mark your own answer as accepted (I don't know if you have to wait a few hours)

Comment: Well, thanks for ackowledging, but the recommendation was really not mine - I merely pointed to that discussion, the real credit goes to those who provided the answers there.